# Native back button works, touch-backbutton crashes?

Tags: android, android-activity

I can go forward and backward in my application using the native back button. If I use the touch-button, the application gets stopped with the attached Stacktrace.

It is only in one view, that contains a WebView. I DON'T want to implement a backbutton for the WebView like all the other people, who asked a similar question here (page back instead of activity back).

I attached also some code of the app. It crashes at the point, where the activity loads the extras (NullPointerException). Can I avoid, that the back-button creates a totally new activity? In other parts of my app, this works without a problem, even if there were extras handed over

What I tried:
Using Bundle and putting the extras directly into the intent.

**Stacktrace:**

```
08-18 22:52:04.308    6982-6982/com.nubage.minepedia E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nubage.minepedia, PID: 6982
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nubage.minepedia/com.nubage.minepedia.ItemsView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.nubage.minepedia.ItemsView.onCreate(ItemsView.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ItemsMenu:**

```
public class ItemsMenu extends Activity {

    private final String MENU_NAME = "items";
    private final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
    private final String KEY_SUBCATEGORY = "subcategory";
```

//.....

```
    public void itemButtonClicked(View view) {
        String parameter = null;
        Log.d("ID: ", String.valueOf(view.getId()));
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.building_blocks_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.building_blocks);
                break;
            case R.id.decoration_blocks_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.decoration_blocks);
                break;
            case R.id.redstone_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.redstone);
                break;
            case R.id.transportation_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.transportation);
                break;
            case R.id.miscellaneous_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.miscellaneous);
                break;
            case R.id.foodstuffs_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.foodstuffs);
                break;
            case R.id.tools_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.tools);
                break;
            case R.id.combat_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.combat);
                break;
            case R.id.brewing_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.brewing);
                break;
            case R.id.materials_id:
                parameter = getString(R.string.materials);
                break;
        }
        Log.d("ItemsMenu - itemButtonClicked() parameter: ", parameter);
        if (parameter != null) {
            Intent itemsView = new Intent(this, ItemsView.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(KEY_CATEGORY, MENU_NAME);
            bundle.putString(KEY_SUBCATEGORY, parameter);
            itemsView.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(itemsView);
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemsView.class:**

```
public class ItemsView extends Activity {

    private final String MENU_NAME = "items";
    private final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
    private final String KEY_SUBCATEGORY = "subcategory";


    GridView gridView;
    GridViewCustomAdapter gridViewCustomAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_items_view);

        String category = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_CATEGORY);
        String subcategory = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_SUBCATEGORY);

        /*if (this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_CATEGORY) != null)
            this.category = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_CATEGORY);
        if (this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_SUBCATEGORY) != null)
            this.subcategory = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_SUBCATEGORY);
*/
        Log.d("ItemsView - onCreate() - Bundle Category: " + category, "Length: " + category.length());
        Log.d("ItemsView - onCreate() - Bundle Category: " + subcategory, "Length: " + subcategory.length());

//        String[] databaseArray = new String[Minepedia_main.database.size()];

//        for (int i=0; i<Minepedia_main.database.size(); ++i)
//            databaseArray[i] = Minepedia_main.database.get(i);

        //Search the Database for wanted entries...
        List<String> resultCollection = new ArrayList<String>(150);
        for (int i=0; i<Minepedia_main.database.size(); ++i) {
            String temp = Minepedia_main.database.get(i);
            String[] split = temp.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

            if (split[2].equals(category) && split[3].equals(subcategory)) {
                resultCollection.add(temp);
            }

            /*if (temp.contains(category) && temp.contains(subcategory)) {
                resultCollection.add(temp);
            }*/
        }

        //List to Array...
        final String[] databaseArray = new String[resultCollection.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<resultCollection.size(); ++i) {
            databaseArray[i] = resultCollection.get(i);
        }

        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewCustomAdapter(this, databaseArray));

        // Handling touch/click Event on GridView Item
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {

                if (Minepedia_main.ONLINE_MODE_ENABLED == false) {
                    String fileName = databaseArray[position].split(Pattern.quote("|"))[0] + ".html";
                    createOfflineIntent(fileName);
                } else {
                    String url = Minepedia_main.PROVIDER + databaseArray[position].split(Pattern.quote("|"))[4];
                    createOnlineIntent(url);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void createOfflineIntent(String fileName) {
        Intent offlineBrowser = new Intent(this, ItemViewDetailOffline.class);
        //offlineBrowser.putExtra("fileName", fileName);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fileName", fileName);
        offlineBrowser.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(offlineBrowser);
    }

    private void createOnlineIntent(String url) {
        Intent onlineBrowser = new Intent(this, ItemViewDetailOnline.class);
        //onlineBrowser.putExtra("url", url);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", url);
        onlineBrowser.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(onlineBrowser);
    }
}
```

**ItemViewDetailOnline.class:**

```
public class ItemViewDetailOnline extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_view_detail_online);

        String url = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_online);
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_view_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_item_view_detail_online.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nubage.minepedia.ItemViewDetailOnline">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_online"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is line 36 in onCreate of ItemsView?

Comment: @zgc7009: String category = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_CATEGORY);

I added the whole content from ItemsView.class. :)

Comment: Check to make sure getExtras() != null before you try to get values from it. `if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){ String category = ... }`

Comment: @zgc7009: I already tried even that. :) Anyway, I really need the 2 Strings there.

Comment: That is the only thing I could think of it possibly being. Everything else either has to be set or it doesn't matter if it is set. For example, if it couldn't find the key it would just set your string to null (I believe). Can you post your code where you are creating your bundle and adding it to your ItemsView.class intent?

Comment: @zgc7009: I can solve the problem if I declare the variables "category" and "subcategory" as static, so they won't be overriden when it comes to a new instance. But this is a very ugly solution.

I added your requested class, it's called "ItemsMenu.class".
Thanks for your help until now! :)

Comment: That seems weird, but progress is progress haha.